# eclipse is not recognizing regular signs such as ";" or "()"

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to write a simple contactManager program and eclipse is not recognizing the basic signs such as ; or ().
there is a Syntax error saying I should write exactly the same signs as I already used, or different irrelevant signs.

I tried deleting the project, the classes and start over, but the problem keeps showing.

```
public class ContactManager {

    Contact [] myFriends;
    int friendsCount;
}
```

> Syntax error on token ";", = expected.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your class definition, other than there isn't really much of a definition.  You only declared two variables, and there are no methods.  Maybe finish writing the class and see what happens.

Comment: Something doesn't add up here. Perhaps a screenshot of the error could help us help you?

Comment: You could try compiling the class directly with `javac`, that would decide whether the problem is with the IDE or there's actually something wrong with your code

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall an updated version of eclipse?

Comment: If you didn't type the code yourself, but copied it from somewhere, see my answer below.

Comment: Try removing the space before the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes word processors or publishing tools replace ASCII characters with similar looking Unicode characters. For example, I get the same error message with `;` ([Unicode character `\u037e`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+037E)) instead of `;` ([Unicode character `\u003b`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+003B)):

If you didn't type the code but copied it from somewhere, make sure that **ASCII semicolons `;`** are used **instead of other Unicode characters that look similar**.